# JQUERY next () img in li? multiple imgs in li

Tags: php, jquery

```
<div id = "listwrapper">
    <ul id = "mylist">                                   
    <?php
        $images = glob("sorted/2017/*.jpg");
        $i = 0;
        foreach((array_reverse($images)) as $image){    
            if ($i == 0){
                    echo "<li>";
            }   
            $i++;                   
            echo'<img id="BR" src="'.$image.'">;

            if($i==4){

                echo"</li>";
                $i = 0;
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
<div>
```

The above script works fine and outputs a `<li>` tag with 4 images in each one. with about 80 images in total.

Now I'm trying to use `next()` and `closest()` to display the next `<img>` in the `<li>` tag when the image is clicked. or if it is the last `<img>` in the `<li>`, then skip to the next `<li>`? seems like it would be easier to change the script and just put each image in its own `<li>` tag..

```
    $('#mylist li img').click(function(){
        var el = document.getElementById('BR');
        var big = document.getElementById('BRBIG');
        var img = document.getElementById('mylist li img');
        imageClicked = $(this).closest('li');

        big.src = imageClicked.find('img').next().next().attr('src');

        $('#brbigcon').show('fadein');
        $('#BRBIG').show(300);
        $('#fs').show(300);


});
```

Is there someway to implement `closest('img')` instead of `closest ('li')`?

Comment: first you might want to change echo'<img id="BR" src="'.$image.'">; to echo'<img class="BR" src="'.$image.'">; and then in you JS change to getElementByClass.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your PHP, you are missing a closing `'` in your echo statement + you shouldn't be recycling the `BR` ID, since IDs must be unique within a document.

Comment: In your html, if the amount of images is not a multiple of 4, the last li never gets closed.

Comment: sorry, my question is not so clear, everything works okay, i get the images in a dynamic gallery sorted by exif date taken from another script. the issue im having is with the jquery part:

        imageClicked = $(this).closest('li');

        big.src = imageClicked.find('img').next().next().attr('src');

^^ this works, but its not dynamic, it find the closest LI element, then goes next , image from that. which works but not what i want, i want the next image from what was clicked:

$('#mylist li img').click(function(){

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id = "listwrapper">
<ul id = "mylist">                                   
<?php
    $images = glob("sorted/2017/*.jpg");
    $i = 0;
    foreach((array_reverse($images)) as $image){    
        if ($i == 0){
                echo "<li>";
        }   
        $i++;                   
        echo '<img class="BR" src="'.$image.'">';

        if($i==4){

            echo "</li>";
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
?>
 </ul>
<div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#mylist .BR').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var big = $('BRBIG');

    big.attr('src', src);

    $('#brbigcon').show('fadein');
    $('#BRBIG').show(300);
    $('#fs').show(300);
 });
```

Comment: unfortunatly not, it displays the first image in the first li tag of listwrapper

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice. In your html, if the amount of images is not a multiple of 4, the last li never gets closed. Here you have another approach to solve it...

```
<div id = "listwrapper">
    <ul id = "mylist">                                   
    <?php
        // Get the array of image urls.
        $images = array_reverse(glob("sorted/2017/*.jpg"));

        // Create the html `img` element of each image.
        $imgs = array_map(function($v) { return "<img class=\"BR\" src=\"".$v."\">"; },$images);

        // Chumk the array in groups of 4 and put each group inside of a `li` element.
        $imgsli = array_map(function($v) { return "<li>".implode("",$v)."</li>"; },array_chunk($imgs,4));

        // Print all the `li` elements.
        echo implode("",$imgsli);
    ?>
    </ul>
<div>
```

About the jquery, this would be my approach...

```
$('#mylist li img').click(function() {

    var $nextImg;

    if ($(this).next('img').length > 0) { // There's more img in current li, get the next one.
        $nextImg = $(this).next('img');
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).closest('li').next('li').length > 0) // There's more li's, go to the first image of the next one.
            $nextImg = $(this).closest('li').next('li').find('img:first');
        else // We are in the last div, go to the first image.
            $nextImg = $('ul#mylist li:first img:first');
    }

    // Now $nextImg is the jQuery object of the right next image. Do what you need to show it.
    ...
});
```

With this you get the right next image according to your indications. Just add the code you want to show the image, etc.

I hope it helps

Comment: thank you for the advice. You are right, if there are less than 4 images it will never close. but anything more than 4 is fine. do you have an idea for the jquery part of the question? 

thanks

Comment: thank you.
 so basically i have :
<li>
 <img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
</li>.

when one image is clicked, i want to get the source of the image next to it. I was wondering why closest('li') works, but closest('img') does not

Comment: Shall i just put each img in its own li tag? it would make easier to work with.. the reason i did it this way is because the gallery will show a maximum of 4 images in each row.

Comment: thank you! i changed..            imageClicked = $(this).closest('li');
            big.src = imageClicked.find('img').next().next().attr('src');   to:

            imageClicked = $(this);
            big.src = imageClicked.next('img').next('img').attr('src');   

it is a bit hacky but it works, even at the last img of the li. BTW i copy pasted your code and it seemed to only want to show the first image from the listwrapper...... 
 Is there anyway to add paragraph lines in these comments? haha. Thank you, sir

Comment: Sorry, there was an error from copy&paste the code from the fiddle I was using to test (I used `span` instead of `img`), that's why it was showing only the first img of the `li`. Now it should work

Comment: Oh yes that works. In the end I am now using index() and parent.index(), to find the number of the li, and the number of the img in the li (that was clicked on) it then expands and shows nxt and previous buttons,, then with some easy maths and using find().eq() i have incorporated it into the next and prev buttons. Thanks for the help!